# Is it possible to compose promises in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, promise, functional-programming, discord

I'm trying to turn my imperative procedural code into a more functional code. My question is how can I compose promises? For example I have this code from my Discord bot:

```
LyricsCommand.searchSong(songName)
      .then(function(url) {
        LyricsCommand.getSongPageURL(url)
          .then(function(url) {
            LyricsCommand.getLyrics(url)
              .then(function(lyrics) {
              // .......... do something ..........
              })
              .catch(function(err) {
                message.reply(err);
                return;
              });
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            message.reply(err);
            return;
          });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        message.reply(err);
        return;
      });
```

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you return from a `.then()` clause, the returned value is wrapped with a promise, so you can [chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) promises together. You also need a only single `.catch()` clause to handle all errors in the chain before it.

In your case you can use `LyricsCommand.getSongPageURL`, and `LyricsCommand.getLyrics` as the callback for `.then()`, since they need only the previous value (`url`), and will return a `url` for the next step. The `message.reply` function can used be in the same way for the `.catch()` block.

```
LyricsCommand.searchSong(songName)
  .then(LyricsCommand.getSongPageURL)
  .then(LyricsCommand.getLyrics)
  .then(function(lyrics) {
    // .......... do something ..........
  })
  .catch(message.reply);
```

If you want to compose promises in a functional way, you'll need to create a compose function that can handle promises (taken from this [article](https://hackernoon.com/lets-compose-promises-309a63225f8a)).

```
const composePromise = (...functions) =>
  initialValue =>
    functions.reduceRight(
      (sum, fn) => Promise.resolve(sum).then(fn),
      initialValue
    );
```

Example (using [SpaceX API](https://github.com/r-spacex/SpaceX-API)):

```js
const composePromise = (...functions) =>
  initialValue => functions.reduceRight(
    (sum, fn) => Promise.resolve(sum).then(fn),
    initialValue
  )
  
const fn = composePromise(
  console.log,
  data => data.rocket.rocket_id,
  res => res.json(),
  url => fetch(url, { method: 'get' })
)

const url = 'https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches/latest';

fn(url).catch(console.log)
```

This is how you'll use `composePromise` with your code:

```
const fn = composePromise(
  lyrics => // do something with lyrics
  LyricsCommand.getLyrics,
  LyricsCommand.getSongPageURL,
  LyricsCommand.searchSong
)
```

and you'll call it like this:

```
fn(songName).catch(message.reply)
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options. Since each of those functions returns a Promise, you can flatten the promise chain, rather than nesting them.

```
LyricsCommand.searchSong(songName)
  .then(url => LyricsCommand.getSongPageURL(url))
  .then(url => LyricsCommand.getLyrics(url))
  .then(function(lyrics) {
    // .......... do something ..........
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    message.reply(err);
  });
```

The single `.catch` will work for the entire chain.

Alternatively, you could use the `async/await` syntax:

```
async function getSong(songName) {
  try {
    const url = await LyricsCommand.searchSong(songName);
    const url2 = await LyricsCommand.getSongPageURL(url);
    const lyrics = await LyricsCommand.getLyrics(url2);
    // .......... do something ..........
  } catch {
    message.reply(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
async function doStuffWithLyrics(songName) {
    try {
        const song = await LyricsCommand.searchSong(songName);
        const songPage = await LyricsCommand.getSongPage(song);
        const lyrics = await LyricsCommand.getLyrics(songPage);
    
        // Do stuff with lyrics
    } catch (err) {
       message.reply(err);
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to, you could do something like:

```
async function doStuffWithLyrics(songName) {
    try {
        const lyrics = await LyricsCommand.getLyrics(await LyricsCommand.getSongPage(await LyricsCommand.searchSong(songName)));

        // Do stuff with lyrics
    } catch (err) {
       message.reply(err);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't save you much and I'd find it harder to read.